# LeetCode - Add Two Numbers, I have a problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was solving coding questions via Leetcode but I am getting the following error.

[image]

When I run the code that I have written on Visual Studio Code, it works, but it doesn't accept it here.

**Following is the code I wrote in VS code**

```
    def addTwoNumbers(l1,l2):
        firstlist = l1[::-1]
        secondlist = l2[::-1]
        
        firstliststr = []
        secondliststr = []
        for i in firstlist:
            firstliststr.append(str(i))
        
        for i in secondlist:
            secondliststr.append(str(i))
        
        firstnumber = ""
        secondnumber=""
        for i in range(len(firstliststr)):
            firstnumber = firstnumber+ firstliststr[i]
        for i in range(len(secondliststr)):
            secondnumber = secondnumber+ secondliststr[i]
        
        firstnumber = int(firstnumber)
        secondnumber = int(secondnumber)
        
        x = firstnumber + secondnumber 
        
        x = str(x)
        x = x[::-1]
        lastlist = []
        for i in x:
            i = int(i)
            lastlist.append(i)

        print(lastlist)
```

**Following is the code I wrote in LeetCode:**

```
    class Solution:
        def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
            firstlist = l1[::-1]
            secondlist = l2[::-1]
            
            firstliststr = []
            secondliststr = []
            for i in firstlist:
                
                firstliststr.append(str(i))
            
            for i in secondlist:
                secondliststr.append(str(i))
            
            firstnumber = ""
            secondnumber=""
            for i in range(len(firstliststr)):
                firstnumber = firstnumber+ firstliststr[i]
            for i in range(len(secondliststr)):
                secondnumber = secondnumber+ secondliststr[i]
            
            firstnumber = int(firstnumber)
            secondnumber = int(secondnumber)
            
            x = firstnumber + secondnumber 
            
            x = str(x)
            x = x[::-1]
            lastlist = []
            for i in x:
                i = int(i)
                lastlist.append(i)
            print(lastlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your local code, l1 and l2 are lists, in leetcode they are of type `[ListNode]`, `ListNode` is a class, and you cannot do `l1[::-1]` because that is not defined.

Try running this code in VS Code:

```
from typing import Optional


class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next


def addTwoNumbers(l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    firstlist = l1[::-1]
    secondlist = l2[::-1]
    
    firstliststr = []
    secondliststr = []
    for i in firstlist:
        firstliststr.append(str(i))
    
    for i in secondlist:
        secondliststr.append(str(i))
    
    firstnumber = ""
    secondnumber = ""
    for i in range(len(firstliststr)):
        firstnumber = firstnumber + firstliststr[i]
    for i in range(len(secondliststr)):
        secondnumber = secondnumber + secondliststr[i]
    
    firstnumber = int(firstnumber)
    secondnumber = int(secondnumber)
    
    x = firstnumber + secondnumber 
    
    x = str(x)
    x = x[::-1]
    lastlist = []
    for i in x:
        i = int(i)
        lastlist.append(i)

    print(lastlist)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    l1 = ListNode(2, ListNode(4, ListNode(3)))
    l2 = ListNode(5, ListNode(6, ListNode(4)))
    addTwoNumbers(l1, l2)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i don't know how can i define it because I just see the ListNode type. Can you please say me, how can i define it?

Comment: Check the edited code

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Yes you should, this is just replicating what happens in leetcode

Comment: You can't reverse a linked list like `l2[::-1]`. Your whole approach needs to change.  In the question they have purposely given the nodes in reverse.

Comment: Now i understood. Thank you so much